# Add Scheduling start date with the event "itemAdding"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I try to add by default a scheduling start date when I create a page or an article.
There is my code :

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
 {

       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;
       ScheduledItem scheduledItem = null;
       if (ScheduledItem.IsScheduledItem(listItem))
       {
           scheduledItem = ScheduledItem.GetScheduledItem(listItem);
       }
       else
       {
           throw new System.ArgumentException
             ("The document library containing this SPListItem must support scheduling",
             "listItem");
       }

       scheduledItem.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
       scheduledItem.ListItem.Update();

       scheduledItem.Schedule();

   }
```

But I have the error which said that listItem is null (because it's not create).
So I need help. Can anyone provide some guidance?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the late of this message but I have an error when I try to execute my code with itemAdded : The file Pages/Article/testart.aspx has been modified by author at the line -> 'scheduledItem.ListItem.Update();' Any ideas?
I think it's because when I create a page, the "edition mode" is activated so there is a conflict...

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, the item has not yet been created in the ItemADDING event. Since you don't seem to need to have your code executed on the adding event, I suppose that you could just move it to the [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded%28v=office.14%29.aspx) receiver, where the item should be normally available.

Comment: Thanks for your help but if I try this, I have the Exception : "The security validation for this page is invalid" when the code try to execute "scheduledItem.ListItem.Update();"...
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to change the line scheduledItem.ListItem.Update(); to properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdate=true; scheduledItem.ListItem.Update(); properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdate=false;

Comment: Sorry for the late of this message but I have an error when I try to execute my code with itemAdded : The file Pages/Article/testart.aspx has been modified by author at the line -> 'scheduledItem.ListItem.Update();' Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try it using "**An Item Was Added**" Event Receiver.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010(v=office.14).aspx

It will work.

Comment: Sorry for the late of this message but I have an error when I try to execute my code with itemAdded : The file Pages/Article/testart.aspx has been modified by author at the line -> 'scheduledItem.ListItem.Update();'
Any ideas?

Comment: Replace "scheduledItem.ListItem.Update();"  with "properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();".
This might Help you.

Comment: That's great but if the user want change directly the option to Immediatly, he can't. So that's why I used ItemAdding.

Comment: I don't get What you want to say.